# How to count text length from root div until focusNode?

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine that I have a node tree (top-level `root`) with a bunch of subnodes, like this:

```
<div id="root" contenteditable="true" >
  Inside div <span>Inside span </span><a>Inside link </a><span>Inside span </span>Inside div again
</div>
```

When I click anywhere inside this `div`, I'll get a `focusNode` based on my click (simple click, not click and hold to make a selection).

```
const selection = window.getSelection();
const focusNode = selection.focusNode; // This is the node where the caret is
```

**QUESTION**

How can I count the text from the `root` until I find the `focusNode`? Traversing all possible children and adding every **text length** along the way. When the `focusNode` is found, return the total value.

**Note:** I am not using jQuery.

```js
function handleClick() {
  const root = document.getElementById('root');
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const focusNode = selection.focusNode;
  
  countTextFromRootToFocus(root,focusNode);
}


function countTextFromRootToFocus(root,focusNode) {

  console.log('Text length from root to focus is: XXX');
}
```

```css
#root {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Click anywhere inside the div</p>
<div id="root" contenteditable="true" onclick="handleClick()">
  Inside div <span>Inside span </span><a>Inside link </a><span>Inside span </span>Inside div again
</div>
```

Comment: what use case would this have? (what are you planning on doing further on with this length/index) - might help with generating solutions :)

Comment: I'm building a mention box just like Twitter's "new tweet" box. Where you can enter '@' and it will auto complete with a list of users. If you inspect Twitter you'll see that every line inside the tweet box is a `<div>` but when you mention somebody, that mention becomes a `<span>` inside the `<div>`. I'm using React and I'll have set the `innerHTML` of the div to create those `<span>` and also delete them. But `innerHTML` resets the caret to the begining of the line. So I need to count where it was, so that I can place it back after changing the html.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abhas9/61n4adrk/

Comment: do you want to find length of only selected text?

Comment: There's no selected text. Just a single click and the selection is just the position of the caret. For example, if you click in the middle of "inside span" you'll be clicking on the `#text` node of that span. I want to count every `#text` node's length from the begining of the root `div` going through all possible `children` until I find the text node. I'll write a pseudo code for that on the question.

Comment: @AbhasTandon blew my mind! That is just great! Write an answer with that code in here if you can. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AbhasTandon do you have a code on how to place the caret based on the same value? Like: "place caret on position 42", regardless of the subnodes and text nodes sequence? The same ideia, but the other way around.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nrx9yvw9/5/ not submitting because it's not my code

Comment: @AbhasTandon thank you again! This is some really nice piece of code!